# Shellcheck recommendation to double-quote variable does not work when piping to cut

Tags: bash, scripts, pipe, syntax

I'm making a script to print ZFS filesystem info - currently in the testing phase, and I'm getting a strange error.

The relevant bit of my initial script is this:

```
zfs_human="$(zfs list | head -n 2 | tail -n 1)"
dfs_human="$(df -h | grep 'zfs' | head -n 1)"
zfs_usedh="$(echo $zfs_human | cut -d ' ' -f2)"
zfs_totah="$(echo $dfs_human | cut -d ' ' -f2)"
echo "$zfs_human"
echo "$dfs_human"
echo "$zfs_usedh"
echo "$zfs_totah"
```

Giving the following output:

```
zfs                      2.31M  5.27T     34.4K  /mnt/zfs
zfs                      5.3T  128K  5.3T   1% /mnt/zfs
2.31M
5.3T
```

However, when I run `shellcheck`, it says I should double-quote the variable names inside the command substitution, this is the output from `shellcheck`:

```
In zfsspace.sh line 5:zfs_usedh="$(echo $zfs_human | cut -d ' ' -f2)"                  ^--------^
SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Did you mean: 
zfs_usedh="$(echo "$zfs_human" | cut -d ' ' -f2)"

In zfsspace.sh line 6:zfs_totah="$(echo $dfs_human | cut -d ' ' -f2)"                  ^--------^
SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Did you mean: 
zfs_totah="$(echo "$dfs_human" | cut -d ' ' -f2)"
```

Then I of course change my code to shellcheck's recommendation:

```
zfs_human="$(zfs list | head -n 2 | tail -n 1)"
dfs_human="$(df -h | grep 'zfs' | head -n 1)"
zfs_usedh="$(echo "$zfs_human" | cut -d ' ' -f2)"
zfs_totah="$(echo "$dfs_human" | cut -d ' ' -f2)"
echo "$zfs_human"
echo "$dfs_human"
echo "$zfs_usedh"
echo "$zfs_totah"
```

But now the output is this:

```
zfs                      2.31M  5.27T     34.4K  /mnt/zfs
zfs                      5.3T  128K  5.3T   1% /mnt/zfs
```

Line 3 and 4 is blank, which means the 3rd and 4th command substitution does not work when following shellcheck's recommendation, but works when not quoting the variable that I echo.

I'm using Bash 5.0.17 on Ubuntu 20.04.1

Can anyone explain this please??? Thanks.

Comment: I suspect it's because the *un*quoted `$zfs_human` is subject to split+glob, as a result of which sequences of whitespace are replaced with the first character of the current `IFS` (by default, a single space). The *quoted* `"$zfs_human"` will retain whatever whitespace is output by the `zfs list` command. You could likely avoid the issue by using `awk` (which treats contiguous whitespace as the delimiter by default) instead of `cut -d ' '`

Comment: Ok thanks - or I could make a directive to ignore the shellcheck warning in this particular instance of course.

Comment: looks that you are trying to print line two head ... tail ... probably easier to use `... | sed -n 2p`

Comment: you could do `read -r filesystem size used avail _ < <(df -hP | grep -m1 zfs)` ... read will squeeze spaces for you.

Comment: ...but my first choice would be to use lsblk.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. As mentioned, still WIP, and trying to figure out the best way to do things. The first line is going to be replaced with a grep statement anyway. And `lsblk` doesn't really give any useful info about the ZFS pool and datasets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `-H` to zfs will remove the headers and separate fields by a single tab instead of arbitrary whitespace, which simplifies parsing considerably. Because `df` don't have an option for removing the header, `findmnt` will be a better choice.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# zfs
read -r zfs_usedh < <(zfs list -H -o used)

# df
read -r zfs_totah < <(findmnt -frnt zfs -o size)

echo "$zfs_usedh"
echo "$zfs_totah"
```

There is no total size, as with `df` so, you have to fall back on traditional math.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

read -d \\n -r avail used total < <(zfs get -Hpo value available,used | \
     awk 'NR < 3 { n+=$1; print $1 } END { print n }' | numfmt --invalid=ignore --to=iec \
)

printf %s\\n $used $total
```

Comment: Fairly certain zfs can produce total size too, then you could use a single read, just add a new variable for every output field.

Comment: Thanks. If you find the parameter for ZFS total size, please let me know. I haven't been able to find it.

Answer (score 0):

As per @steeldrivers suggestion, I replaced `cut` with `awk`, and this works as intended.

```
zfs_human="$(zfs list | head -n 2 | tail -n 1)"
dfs_human="$(df -h | grep 'zfs' | head -n 1)"
zfs_usedh="$(echo "$zfs_human" | awk -F " " '{print $2}')"
zfs_totah="$(echo "$dfs_human" | awk -F " " '{print $2}')"
echo "$zfs_human"
echo "$dfs_human"
echo "$zfs_usedh"
echo "$zfs_totah"
```

For consistency, I believe this is the best solution to preserve the syntax recommended by `shellcheck`, thus consistently using `awk` over `cut` for string splitting, unless there is a specific reason to use `cut`.